# typescript unable to find modules on windows?

Tags: windows, typescript, webpack, aurelia, webpack-dev-server

I've got the following errors being emitted from webpack dev server, I didn't get these errors before I migrated to windows.

```
[default] C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf-ui\custom_typings\fetch.d.ts:1:1 
    File 'C:/Users/xeno/IdeaProjects/rpf-ui/node_modules/@types/whatwg-fetch/index.d.ts' not found.
[default] C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf-ui\src\security\register\RegistrationSvc.ts:4:45 
    Cannot find module 'src/security/authn/credentials/UsernamePasswordCredentials'.
[default] C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf-ui\typings\globals\whatwg-fetch\index.d.ts:88:11 
    Cannot find name 'ReadableStream'.
[default] Checking finished with 3 errors
```

I had more failures before I ran this. Worth saying all of those files are available at those locations, though I'm concerned that they're being shown with `/` and not `\` since this is on windows and wasn't happening on linux.

that said my versions all look more recent than what I was running on linux.

```
 npm -v && au --version && npm list typescript aurelia-framework webpack
3.10.3
0.18.0
rpf@0.1.12 C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\rpf-ui
+-- aurelia-framework@1.0.2
+-- typescript@2.0.2
+-- typings@1.3.3
| `-- typings-core@1.4.1
|   `-- typescript@1.8.7
`-- webpack@2.1.0-beta.21
```

how can I fix these errors? warnings? I can add information, but I'm not sure what's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too ensure your using the same versions as you were on Linux I would go back to that working version of the project on that other dev enviroment and run `npm shrinkwrap`.

This will create a `npm-shrinkwrap.json`. With this new file go back to your Windows dev environment delete the local `node_modules` directory and run `npm cache clean`.

Then go about reinstalling the modules with `npm install`.

Also check you're running the same version of `node` and `au` as you were on the Linux environment.

Failing that it's likely an issue with one of the modules you're using not using the `path` module to sanitize file paths across platforms.

In which case I would recommend running a seperate developer enviroment on Windows within a VM / Container (Vagrant, Docker), or try using `bash` for Windows as your shell.

Comment: well `au` wouldn't have anything to do with it, because that doesn't get run as part of webpack. I changed my ci to run build, even when not doing a release, that's in a docker environment, determined it has the same issues. ran `shrinkwrap --dev` (after shrinkwrap didn't work), and that resolved the issue (at least in ci, though one of these is definitely a my code issue. `ReadableStream` isn't)

Comment: guess I'll have to go through dev deps one at a time.

Comment: Glad you found the fault. 